# Multiple Values in Begin with Declare in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hi I want to use multiple values to the script to be executed at the same time
I have two variables and one of the variable will have multiple values.
Can I user multiple values for VAR_INVC_ID in the begin statement so that the scripts take action on two invc_id having sgmt_i =2?

```
DECLARE
   VAR_INVC_ID   INT;
   VAR_SGMT_ID   INT;
BEGIN
   VAR_INVC_ID := 19762884; 19764495;
   VAR_SGMT_ID := 2;

   INSERT INTO IORDL
      SELECT 0,
         DC_ID,
         WHSE_ID,
         ORD_ID,
         SGMT_ID,
         ORDD_ID,
         CUST_ID,
         PROD_ID,
         INVC_ID,
         'A',
         ORD_QTY,
         0,
         SHIP_QTY,
         NULL,
         'D',
         'MK',
         'FLOW',
         ORDER_TYPE_ID,
         '011',
         NULL,
         'N',
         NULL,
         'exceedMK',
         SYSDATE,
         NULL,
         NULL,
         NULL,
         UNIT_SHIP_CSE,
         PRDD_ID,
         NULL,
         OSTA_ID,
         ORD_RQST_DEL_DT,
         ORD_RQST_DEL_TIM,
         DEFER_BILL_DT,
         PCDE_ID,
         COMMODITY_TYPE,
         SUB_TYPE,
         ORDER_DT,
         ORDER_TIM,
         RTL_COST,
         AVG_CSE_WGT,
         CSE_UNIT,
         FT_ID,
         FTD_ID,
         SELD_ID
    FROM IORDL
   WHERE (ORD_ID, SGMT_ID, ORDD_ID) NOT IN
                (SELECT ORD_ID, SGMT_ID, ORDD_ID
                   FROM IORDL
                  WHERE     INVC_ID = VAR_INVC_ID
                        AND SGMT_ID = VAR_SGMT_ID
                        AND ERCD_ID = 'MK')
         AND ERCD_ID = 'SP'
         AND INVC_ID = VAR_INVC_ID
         AND SGMT_ID = VAR_SGMT_ID;

-- Backup ishd records;
INSERT INTO ISHD_BKP
   SELECT *
    FROM ISHD
   WHERE INVC_ID = VAR_INVC_ID AND SGMT_ID = VAR_SGMT_ID;

 -- UPDATE ishs spmd_units for corresponding ishd records
MERGE INTO ISHS SH
    USING (  SELECT CURR_PAL_NO, SUM (PROD_QTY / UNIT_SHIP_CSE) QTY
               FROM ISHD
              WHERE INVC_ID = VAR_INVC_ID AND SGMT_ID = VAR_SGMT_ID
           GROUP BY CURR_PAL_NO) SD
       ON (SH.CURR_PAL_NO = SD.CURR_PAL_NO)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
  UPDATE SET
     SH.SPMD_UNITS = SH.SPMD_UNITS - SD.QTY, CHANGE_USER = 'exceedMK';

-- DELETE ishd records;
DELETE ISHD
WHERE INVC_ID = VAR_INVC_ID AND SGMT_ID = VAR_SGMT_ID;

-- UPDATE IORD

UPDATE IORD SET OSTA_ID='CLO' WHERE INVC_ID = VAR_INVC_ID AND SGMT_ID =      VAR_SGMT_ID;

COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: I am unable to execute this statement. Error at Line 5.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I tries using BEGIN
   VAR_INVC_ID := (19762884,19764495); still error

Comment: either you need use collection to hold multiple values or user some thing like bellow  declare two variable and use them into sql statement with union all  (select VAR_INVC_ID1 from dual
            union all select VAR_INVC_ID2 from dual) and use in instead of = condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your inv_id variable should be declared as an array of integers

```
DECLARE
   VAR_INVC_ID_TAB  UTL_NLA_ARRAY_INT;
   VAR_SGMT_ID   INT;
BEGIN
   VAR_INVC_ID_TAB := UTL_NLA_ARRAY_INT(19762884,19764495);
   VAR_SGMT_ID := 2;

   INSERT INTO IORDL
      SELECT 0,
         DC_ID,
         WHSE_ID,
         ORD_ID,
         SGMT_ID,
         ORDD_ID,
         CUST_ID,
         PROD_ID,
         INVC_ID,
         'A',
         ORD_QTY,
         0,
         SHIP_QTY,
         NULL,
         'D',
         'MK',
         'FLOW',
         ORDER_TYPE_ID,
         '011',
         NULL,
         'N',
         NULL,
         'exceedMK',
         SYSDATE,
         NULL,
         NULL,
         NULL,
         UNIT_SHIP_CSE,
         PRDD_ID,
         NULL,
         OSTA_ID,
         ORD_RQST_DEL_DT,
         ORD_RQST_DEL_TIM,
         DEFER_BILL_DT,
         PCDE_ID,
         COMMODITY_TYPE,
         SUB_TYPE,
         ORDER_DT,
         ORDER_TIM,
         RTL_COST,
         AVG_CSE_WGT,
         CSE_UNIT,
         FT_ID,
         FTD_ID,
         SELD_ID
    FROM IORDL
   WHERE (ORD_ID, SGMT_ID, ORDD_ID) NOT IN
                (SELECT ORD_ID, SGMT_ID, ORDD_ID
                   FROM IORDL
                  WHERE     INVC_ID in (select COLUMN_VALUE from table(VAR_INVC_ID_TAB))
                        AND SGMT_ID = VAR_SGMT_ID
                        AND ERCD_ID = 'MK')
         AND ERCD_ID = 'SP'
         AND INVC_ID = VAR_INVC_ID
         AND SGMT_ID = VAR_SGMT_ID;

-- Backup ishd records;
INSERT INTO ISHD_BKP
   SELECT *
    FROM ISHD
   WHERE INVC_ID in (select COLUMN_VALUE from table(VAR_INVC_ID_TAB)) 
     AND SGMT_ID = VAR_SGMT_ID;

 -- UPDATE ishs spmd_units for corresponding ishd records
MERGE INTO ISHS SH
    USING (  SELECT CURR_PAL_NO, SUM (PROD_QTY / UNIT_SHIP_CSE) QTY
               FROM ISHD
              WHERE INVC_ID in (select COLUMN_VALUE from table(VAR_INVC_ID_TAB)) AND SGMT_ID = VAR_SGMT_ID
           GROUP BY CURR_PAL_NO) SD
       ON (SH.CURR_PAL_NO = SD.CURR_PAL_NO)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
  UPDATE SET
     SH.SPMD_UNITS = SH.SPMD_UNITS - SD.QTY, CHANGE_USER = 'exceedMK';

-- DELETE ishd records;
DELETE ISHD
WHERE INVC_ID in (select COLUMN_VALUE from table(VAR_INVC_ID_TAB)) AND SGMT_ID = VAR_SGMT_ID;

-- UPDATE IORD

UPDATE IORD SET OSTA_ID='CLO' WHERE INVC_ID in (select COLUMN_VALUE from table(VAR_INVC_ID_TAB)) AND SGMT_ID =      VAR_SGMT_ID;

COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: Hi @Mukesh, did this answer solve your problem? can you please mark the question as answered and mark the answer as accepted? it will help both our reputations by adding us points =)